# Scrollbehaviour weird jumping in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

So I configured my rouse.scrollBehaviour.ts file in Nuxt 3. Here it is:

```
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.$router.options.scrollBehavior = (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }
    return { left: 0, top: 0, behaviour: "smooth" };
  };
});
```

The problem is that I think it's scrolling earlier than the pages load, so there is a weird jumping effect on the pages.

Here is a video of the problem:
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22452368/154849559-3974fc01-e265-486b-865b-55ee03053fa8.mp4

Can you please help me what is the problem here? Or is there a bug in Nuxt 3?

Comment: Probably not a bug with Nuxt3 by itself but rather an issue with a component being unmounted later, or some CSS that is making a transition maybe. You could use the devtools (`animations` tab) to find out what is happening IMO.

Comment: I don't think it's cause by animations. Other people experiencing it to... :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution mentioned in this [nuxt issue](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/1707#issuecomment-1104540588)

```js
// app/router.options.js
export default {
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 }
  },
}
```